# Delete query throws an error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I am facing this type of error in Netbeans when executing my query:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'name=null' at line 1

My Code:

```
enterbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "delete from MovieRecords where id=" + l_id.getText() + "and name=" + j_name.getName();

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 

    }

});
```

Comment: You have no space between AND and whatever comes before AND. Also see about NULL comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this syntax errors and SQL Injection you have to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead for example :

```
String sql = "delete from MovieRecords where id= ? and name = ?";
PreparedStatement pstm = ccon.prepareStatement(sql);
pstm.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(l_id.getText()));
pstm.setString(2, j_name.getName());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

---

Your real problem is that String should be between two `''` (but i don't advice to use this way, use `PreparedStatement` instead)

```
String sql = "delete from MovieRecords where id = " + l_id.getText() + " and name='" + j_name.getName()+"'";
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------^----------------------^
```

---

Like [Usagi Miyamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899193/usagi-miyamoto) mention in his comment :

> Any operator (except `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL`) will return `NULL` if any of
>   its operand is `NULL`. That makes the `=` comparison and also the `AND`
>   return `NULL`, and the WHERE clause convert `NULL` to **`FALSE`**, as per
>   standard SQL..

So if you want to delete non null you have to check the values is not null before you use it
Else to get where col is null you can use IS NULL instead of equal operator `=`

Comment: What about `NULL` handling ?

Comment: @sagi whis preparedStatement it is not necessary so for example example i can delete MovieRecords where id = 1 and name = null ;) this not cause any problem

Comment: then the OP should to check the value before he/she use it @sagi this is logic

Comment: `WHERE id = 1 AND name = NULL` will never be `TRUE`, so it would never delete any rows...

Comment: any explication @UsagiMiyamoto why it never be true?

Comment: Any operator (except `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL`) will return `NULL` if any of its operand is `NULL`. That makes the `=` comparison and also the `AND` return `NULL`, and the `WHERE` clause convert `NULL` to `FALSE`, as per standard SQL...

Comment: wow this is really correct i totally forgot this, ok i will include this information in my answer if you don't mind of course, and thank you for the information @UsagiMiyamoto

Comment: One could circumvent this by an `OR` clause to the comparison, or with the `COALESCE()` function

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto i already mention your comment in my answer is that fair? :)

Comment: It's fine, thanks.